# Javascript to Perl Array/Hash Conversion

Tags: javascript, arrays, perl, hash

I've got the following code in JavaScript:

```
    _pCombos = [
        [{row:9,col:0},{row:1,col:9},{row:1,col:2},{row:1,col:3},{row:1,col:4}],
        [{row:0,col:0},{row:0,col:1},{row:0,col:2},{row:0,col:3},{row:0,col:4}],
        [{row:2,col:0},{row:2,col:1},{row:2,col:2},{row:2,col:3},{row:2,col:4}],
        [{row:0,col:0},{row:1,col:1},{row:2,col:2},{row:1,col:3},{row:0,col:4}],
    ];
```

I would access it like this

```
    _pCombos[0][0].row (result = 9)
    _pCombos[0][1].col (result = 9)
```

How can I build this Hash/Array in Perl? I can't figure it out other than doing 10 different loops and building it that way. But I want it to be there before the code runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my $_pCombos = [
    [{row => 9,col => 0},{row => 1,col => 9},{row => 1,col => 2},{row => 1,col => 3},{row => 1,col => 4}],
    [{row => 0,col => 0},{row => 0,col => 1},{row => 0,col => 2},{row => 0,col => 3},{row => 0,col => 4}],
    [{row => 2,col => 0},{row => 2,col => 1},{row => 2,col => 2},{row => 2,col => 3},{row => 2,col => 4}],
    [{row => 0,col => 0},{row => 1,col => 1},{row => 2,col => 2},{row => 1,col => 3},{row => 0,col => 4}],
    ];

print $_pCombos->[0][0]{row}, "\n";
print $_pCombos->[0][1]{col}, "\n";
```

will print

```
9
9
```

if you want to maintain the javascript syntax, you can use json, like this:

```
use JSON::XS;

my $_pCombos_JSON_normalized = <<'END';
[
 [{"row":9,"col":0},{"row":1,"col":9},{"row":1,"col":2},{"row":1,"col":3},{"row":1,"col":4}],
 [{"row":0,"col":0},{"row":0,"col":1},{"row":0,"col":2},{"row":0,"col":3},{"row":0,"col":4}],
 [{"row":2,"col":0},{"row":2,"col":1},{"row":2,"col":2},{"row":2,"col":3},{"row":2,"col":4}],
 [{"row":0,"col":0},{"row":1,"col":1},{"row":2,"col":2},{"row":1,"col":3},{"row":0,"col":4}]
]
END

my $_pCombos = decode_json($_pCombos_JSON_normalized);

print $_pCombos->[0][0]{row}, "\n";
print $_pCombos->[0][1]{col}, "\n";
```

will also print

```
9
9
```

Comment: @P.Henderson: Is this what you you wanted? I assumed you needed a way to translate JavaScript notation to Perl.